# converting .string file format into php array format

Tags: php, regex, arrays

Hope that you are doing file

So here is my question i have a xyz.string file that is used for translation.Please find the a small part of file below.

```
/* name for an item that is duplicated in the UI, based on the original name */
"%@ (Copy)" = "%@ (kopi)";

/* display name for a book page template that is the first page of that section */
"%@ (First)" = "%@ (Første)";

/* display name for a book page template that represents a hardcover cover. the second argument is the cover type. */
"%@ (Hardcover, %@)" = "%1$@ (Hard innbinding, %2$@)";

/* display name for a book page template that represents a softcover cover. the second argument is the cover type. */
"%@ (Softcover, %@)" = "%1$@ (myk innbinding, %2$@)";
```

i want to convert the translation i.e in a php array like

```
array(
array{
"%@ (First)"=>"%@ (Første)"
},
array
{
"@ (Hardcover, %@)"=>"%1$@ (Hard innbinding, %2$@)"
}
)
```

and so on.The format that is specified is not mandatory but it should be something that i can workaround with.

Following is the specification of the file format

- key-value pairs are delimited with the equal character (=), and
  terminated by a semicolon (;).
- keys and values are surrounded by double quotes (“)
- place-holders look can be: %.2f, %d, %1$s (regular expression for
  placeholders: /%[\d|.]*\$*\d*[dsf]{1}\b+/)
- comments start at the beginning of the line and span the whole line
  or multiple lines
- single-line comments start with double slashes (//) multi-line
  comments are enclosed in /* */
- a comment is assigned to the next key-value pair unless there are any
  blank lines in between

**I know this can be achieved through PREG_MATCH_ALL but i am not able to create a nice regular expression**

below is my code

```
$str=file_get_contents($_FILES['string']['tmp_name']);
preg_match_all("|(\".+\"\;)|s",preg_quote($str),$match);
echo "<pre/>";print_r($match);die;
```

the exact string i am getting after file_get_content is following

```
/* name for an item that is duplicated in the UI, based on the original name */ "%@ (Copy)" = "%@ (kopi)"; /* display name for a book page template that is the first page of that section */ "%@ (First)" = "%@ (Første)"; /* display name for a book page template that represents a hardcover cover. the second argument is the cover type. */ "%@ (Hardcover, %@)" = "%1$@ (Hard innbinding, %2$@)";
```

If anyone can help me in this it will be much appreciated

Thanks
Ryan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Lord, Regex:

```
"([^"]+)"\s*=\s*"([^"]+)";
```

***Explanations***:

```
"([^"]+)"     # Every thing between double quotes
\s*=\s*       # Equal sign preceded or followed by any number of spaces
"([^"]+)";    # Again every thing between double quotes that ends to a ;
```

PHP code:

```
$text = file_get_contents($_FILES['string']['tmp_name']);
preg_match_all('#"([^"]+)"\s*=\s*"([^"]+)";#', $text, $match);
$translate = array_combine($match[1], $match[2]);
print_r($translate);
```

The **output** for your sample text will be:

```
Array
(
    [%@ (Copy)] => %@ (kopi)
    [%@ (First)] => %@ (FÃ¸rste)
    [%@ (Hardcover, %@)] => %1$@ (Hard innbinding, %2$@)
    [%@ (Softcover, %@)] => %1$@ (myk innbinding, %2$@)
)
```

Comment: i thought it would work but its not working i am not getting anything in the match array please find the exact string that i am getting after file_get_content in my nxt comment

Comment: /* name for an item that is duplicated in the UI, based on the original name */ "%@ (Copy)" = "%@ (kopi)"; /* display name for a book page template that is the first page of that section */ "%@ (First)" = "%@ (Første)"; /* display name for a book page template that represents a hardcover cover. the second argument is the cover type. */ "%@ (Hardcover, %@)" = "%1$@ (Hard innbinding, %2$@)";

Comment: yes its working with the string but not with the file content "STRANGE" i think its a file encoding problem following the link to the .strings file.if you can give it a look it would be great. https://www.dropbox.com/s/exj32uauknjut2x/Localizable.strings

Answer (score 0):

You could just read the wohle string and then use: [explode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

```
$array = explode(';', $string);
```

Comment: explode won't work as the comments in the top can have ; and comments will also come in the array

Comment: Oh, ok!
How about: explode('";' ."\n", $string)?

Comment: nops the str that i am getting doesn't have a new line moreover it is not reliable as well